# How to retrieve ALL metadata in vscode

Tags: apex, api

I'd rather not have to type out all the metadata types in the package.xml but i'm not seeing any other way to do it?

Comment: You might have to use a separate tool like the Package Builder at the free cloudtoolkit.co site.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use this VS Code extension

[Salesforce Package.xml Generator Extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator)

This extension provides an User Interface to choose metadata components for Package.xml file for development against sandboxes or DE orgs (Org Development Model with VS Code). This is similar to Eclipse Force.com IDE Add/Remove Metadata Components option.

Affiliation : I am the developer for this extension. It is free to use.[image]

Comment: +1 from me @Vignaesh, it is helpful !!

Comment: Vignaesh Ram good extension, but is there a way to stop 'Processing Metadata' command? After click 'select all' button, the extension is automatically processing all of the selected metadata components which seems unnessessary when you only want to get all of the metadata.

Comment: Once you've saved your manifest.xml the next step to actually download the metadata is to run the command: SFDX: Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org

Answer (score 10):

You can now use the org browser in VSCode to retrieve specific metadata types or individual files: https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/org-browser/

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried wild card *? It will retrieve all custom metadata of the org

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomMetadata</name>
    </types>
    <version>45.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Has anybody had any success using this wild card with sfdx? I know it works using ant... but I keep getting an error when using sfdx force:source:retrieve. Here is the error:ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  The specified metadata type is unsupported: [Custom​Metadata]

Comment: Yes @Rodrigo. This works for me now (version 50.0).

Answer (score 2):

I created a `Package.xml` that contains all the metadata types and wildcards so you can pull down the whole org.

The Gist is here: https://gist.github.com/shanerk/d9fec40ddd096cac44cab6d2fd16f5c2

That being said, the Salesforce Extensions for VSCode have native functionality to retrieve all the org metadata which should be used unless you have a compelling reason for a more customized process.

Comment: The wildcard doesn't seem to work for some metadata such as the custom object.

Comment: Do not trust wildcard and the wildcard does not work for all of metadata types.

Comment: This definitely works for most scenarios and has been used by many folks.  Additional info in the comments on the Gist https://gist.github.com/shanerk/d9fec40ddd096cac44cab6d2fd16f5c2#comments