# How to backup Production metadata / is there a better way to manipulate change set components via platform?

Tags: metadata

**Context:**

I am trying to backup my product enviornment's metadata to a sandbox using change set. It includes almost everthing so the amount of components is huge.

**Original Question:**

Currently I'm creating a change set for a sandbox, I have added many change set components, in fact it is up to a amount of 1300.

When I failed uploading the change set facing 3 errors, I wanted to delete 3 components, but immediately I found out I have to search these three components manually.

[image]

The page is setted 25 components per page, with no keyword search function, no tag function, no re-order by name/type function. It is very hard for a large amount of components.

Is there a better way to do so? Or is my way of using this 'change set' function going to a wrong direction?

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/335139/edit) your question to clarify the context of use for your change set? With this many components I wonder if you should be creating a package of some form instead.

Comment: @philW context added. Thank you.

Comment: Could you simply create a new sandbox from production, thus taking all the metadata directly, and subsequently delete those items you don't want? (Also, why would you want to exclude stuff here but keep it on production?)

Comment: Yes it is useful, but the backup thing is kind of schedually, so the upcoming backup is still using the change set to save all of the metadata. It's inevitable I guess?

Comment: Sorry I overlook your point, The 'exclude stuff'  is only because I want to make sure the whole 'using change set to backup metadata is doable' thing, so I need to delete some of the error components to go through the whole change set uploading and release flow...

Comment: An alternative is to use an IDE (e.g. VSCode or IntelliJ IDEA + IC2) to extract the metadata from your org and actually version control that metadata in git (e.g. github, bitbucket, gitlab or a locally hosted git server), or to even ZIP it up and "version control" it as a document on Google Drive or similar.

Comment: Thank you Phil that is very helpful. TBH the platform way is very struggling. Is it possible for more of your time because I'm wondering is there any document or example for the 'IDE way', and also how to recovery from the ZIP or extracted metadata. You know the release of the Production is strict (test covery 75% and so on). Thank you again it is very kind of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your motivation is to provide a way of backing up your production org configuration (metadata), if you want a way to selectively restore from that backup, I recommend a different approach:

1. Create (or refresh) a sandbox from your production org.
2. Use an IDE, like VSCode, to connect to that sandbox and extract all metadata. Exactly how this operates depends on the IDE. An example of how for VSCode is covered in [this previous Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252802/how-to-retrieve-all-metadata-in-vscode).
3. Either:

   1. Place this into git as a project (again you can find some discussions elsewhere on this, for example [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264450/how-do-salesforce-developers-using-visual-studio-code-use-github)).
   2. Zip it all up and upload it somewhere like Google Drive where you can "version control" the whole thing together.
4. When you want to recover metadata, create a Sandbox and restore those pieces of metadata you want by pushing/deploying just those from your IDE.
5. Create a Change Set in the normal way and upload it to production.

Comment: My only question: is creating a sandbox a must-to-do every time I want to backup? Can I copy the production metadata to a existed sandbox by 'updating' ?

Comment: You may even be able to skip step 1 and extract the metadata directly from production to your IDE, but that is more risky and may not work in some cases. Added that you could refresh an existing sandbox.

Comment: Thank you! Wish you a good day/night!